# Re-programming the output on a Magtek MagWedge

Tags: language-agnostic

I am trying to reprogram the the output of my Magtek MagWedge and I cant find any documentation on how the syntax to send to output just the cc number from my cc swipe reader and not of the other data

Below is the example configuration, however I have no clue how to change these values to.

Comment:Set up IntelliPIN to Required Configuration
/rawxact 50B01001011
/rawxact 50E10000000
/rawxact 940101010101010101
/rawxact 564
 Comment:99{{SN}}
/rawsend 52
 Comment:50Z00000110
/rawsend 42Setup Done

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to get the USBMSR Demo program and then send message 01 03 then send 02, then restart the application and send 01 03 send msg then 02 send msg and it fixed it for me.